# tensorflow not improving during trainning

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm starting to study neural Networks. So I started to program some easy neural networks in Python with TensorFlow.
I'm trying to construct one with the MNIST database.

The problem that I have is: when trainning the loss function doesn't decrease. It gets stuck in 60000 that is the number of traininning images.

I've realized that the prediction that it does is all full of zeros. Here it is the code (Also I'm new in this platform so I'm sorry if there is something wrong in the post):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from keras.datasets import mnist # subroutines for fetching the MNIST dataset
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils # utilities for one-hot encoding of ground truth values

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = np.reshape(x_train,[60000,784])
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10) # One-hot encode the labels


x_test = np.reshape(x_test,[10000,784])
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10) # One-hot encode the labels


input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Input')
output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'Output')

syn0 = tf.Variable(2*tf.random_uniform([784,10],seed=1)-1, name= 'syn0')
bias = tf.Variable(2*tf.random_uniform([10],seed=1)-1, name= 'syn0')

syn0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#model

l1 = tf.sigmoid((tf.matmul(input,syn0) + bias),name='layer1')
error = tf.square(l1-output,name='error')
loss = tf.reduce_sum(error, name='cost')



#optimizer
with tf.name_scope('trainning'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)


#session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


#trainning
for i in range (100):
    _,lossNow =  sess.run([train,loss],{input: x_train,output: y_train})
    print(lossNow)

#print debug 
print("Finally, the coeficients are: " , sess.run(tf.transpose(syn0)))
print()
pred = sess.run(l1,{input: x_test,output: y_test})
print("Next prediction: " ,  pred)
print()
print("Final Loss: ", sess.run(loss,{input: x_test,output: y_test}))


#print graph

sess.close
```

After few iterations this is what I get:

```
[[ 150000.]]
[[ 60000.]]
[[ 60000.]]
[[ 60000.]]
[[ 60000.]]
```

It seems that the loss gets stuck. I've tried to change the learning_rate and I've added more layers just to try but I get the same result.

Hope you can help me! And thank you! :D

Comment: can you decrease the learning rate and recheck? It will get slower but will have a better chance to converge

Comment: Looks like you override the weights to 0s. Never use 0s as your weight initializers.

Comment: @Sorin Thank you! But if you look at the code I was trying different inicializations. At the beggining I did random inicialization with zero mean. But still same result

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I've tried with 0.001 and I get exactly the same output. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: can you try more iterations? At what point does the loss stop decreasing?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan At the beggining I was trying with 100 iterations. After that I realize that after the second/third iteration the lost stops decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here are two problems. First is that you sum up all the 60000 data points in your set to compute your loss function instead of using mini batches. That makes your loss function extremely steep with very flat minimums. Second is that you've found a local minimum of the loss function and because of the steepness of the function you've got locked there.

One more problem is that you use sigmoid instead of softmax. If you check your predicted values they are all zeros. With sigmoid you can have this kind of prediction since all outputs are independent and there is no normalization like with softmax (the sum of the output of the softmax is always 1).

Comment: As you said, the problem was that I was using sigmoid instead of softmax. Now, the loss function keeps decreasing. But I don't understand well what you say about the mini batches. Do you mean that I have to select only few data to calculate the loss? Which part of data should I select? Thank you very much! @Andrey

Comment: Usually you divide your data into smaller batches (like 10-100 pieces, say n). Then you perform the gradient descent taking on each step random set of  n points from your data and calculating the loss function only using these n points. In tensorflow there is a special function that gives you a batch of training data of given size. You need to import it by "from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data"

Comment: this function is only for MNIST dataset. And you need to activate it from the imported object "mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)". And then you can use it like "batch_x , batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(n)". Where batch_x are the images, batch_y are the labels, and n is the batch size you want to use. Check documentation for details

Answer (score 0):

For training, did you try executing the node "l1" is session.run(), it is the one that actually does the computation. It is necessary for training also, your error and loss will depend upon the output of "l1", if you are not executing in the session, then loss will not come correctly.

error = tf.square(l1-output,name='error')

See in this line you are calculating error with l1-output, output here are the ground truth but "l1" will not have any value unless you compute it through graph under session.run().

Can you try with below command and check the outputs

predictions, _,lossNow =  sess.run([l1,train,loss],{input: x_train,output: y_train})

Also, instead of using "-" sign while calculating the error (l1-output), please use tensorflow operators like show [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/subtract)